# Determine the ID of this cactus

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents, cactus

The first picture is from early spring, the second is a more recent picture.

I have never seen this type of cactus before and would appreciate if some could identify it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like some kind of Cholla.

Answer (score 4):

After extensively combing over google images for the Cylindropuntia and Austrocylindropuntia genus, I have determined that the particular species in question is:

Cylindropuntia spinosior fa. monstruosa

Comment: Nice one! I'm glad my inkling towards some type of Opuntia was somewhat on-track.